# Build WebRTC for Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I want to build WebRTC for Android on CentOS. Can anyone help me to build WebRTC. I want to change codec from opus to g729 for audio calling.

Also guide me for how to change codec after building it.

Comment: Checkout this tutorial [Building a WebRTC Client for Android](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/)

Comment: Thank you , I have checked that , but can not successfully build webrtc .While compiling there is no any Debug is generated in /src/out/

Comment: Try Sinch API https://www.sinch.com/products/webrtc/

Comment: I think you have to look into this article if you still needed it. [Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)